# How can i resolve Google Response code 204

Tags: java, android

We have Android app, in that Android app there is an process checking the internet...in that area background process,they provide http://google.com url...in that case our app hit the google.com get the response code 200 from Google.com

past 8 years it's works perfectly... now its not working...

we have debugged our app...we found the response from the Google website 204 instead of 200

instead of Google if we use any other website its works perfectly..

Can any one help us with us, what is the exact issue...

we can't update either,we can't access the field devices,bcoz this connectivity issue..

We have checked with other websites instead of google its working fine...google alone doesn't work...its respond 204,we have checked Google response code in http checker its only 200..

Comment: Response status Code 204 means HTTP request has been successfully completed, and there is no message body. You have to check with your API. Actually is it any Google API or custom API?

Comment: Bro Neega problem ah konjam theliva solringala?

Comment: 204 response code also fine...but Inga developers enna pannitanga =200 vantha mattum check panni next page poramathiri pannirukanga entire application internet check panra option intha methodla work aguthu...

Comment: Bro actual ah Backend la avanga pannathu correct bro, normal ah internet check pann, backend la irrunthu entha response message um theva illa bro, apadi send panna athu data wastage, so avanga empty body ah send pandraanga, Neega front end la thaan bro itha handle pannanum 204 vanthaalum, navigate work panna vaikanum

Comment: ok bro,thank you...field la update panna option ethum iruka bro..our app not in Play Store...

Comment: Field nu etha bro solla varinga?Enna puriyala bro!

Comment: Bro,nanga oru company, engaloda customersta applications iruku...nanga inga development panni signed apk install panni anupiruvom..custom Android device

Comment: Oh kk bro! apdi naa neega backend la update panna pothum bro athu front end la reflect aaydum existing app instaaled users kum.

Comment: but how is it possible bro... back-end la update panna epdi...nama update push pannama athu solve agum

Comment: Bro for example ipo neega soldera api la body empty ah varathuthaan problem, so 204 varuthu, incase of front end la antha api ah trigger pandrapa backend la irrunthu body la data vanchuna inga response code 200 varum, so code normal ah work aagum. So body la message ah send panna backend team support thaan veanum

Comment: bro ippo field la iruka Android applications la update panna mudiyuma...we can change the code here... but field la update panna mudiyathu..

Comment: Bro backend la change panna front end la reflect aagum bro, but athu neega front end la potruka code poruthu

Comment: thanks bro...but engaluku database illayam bro ipoo than soldranga, actual ah nan quality department, developer illa.. developer releive agitanga ippo sudden ah intha issue came, thanks for the clarification bro

Comment: Welcome Bro! Vera ethavthu doubt naalum kealunga bro, Help Pandrea

Comment: Kandipa bro ,thank you so much for the clarification bro, bro oru help nan ippo android padikalanu iruken ippo kotlin already study pannitu iruken, direct ah android padikalama illa kotlin mudichitu android development pathi padikalama??

Comment: Kotlin first full ah paduchu strong aagikonga bro then android ponga!

Comment: Hi bro,android related ah oru help bro can you help us..

Comment: Yes bro, sollunga,

Comment: fieldla iruka enga applications ah patch mathiri panni api ah change panna mudiyuma..

Comment: front end la API change pannanum na, neega code ah maathiaaganum so athuku oru Update release pannanum. If backend la change panna update theva irrukaathu

Comment: code ah change pannitom bro but ippo update push panna options illa ungaluku ethum vali theriyuma update push panna...apk customersku share pana koodathu..

Comment: Play store thaan bro orey way! other chance kammi thaan